# Как вывести полученное значение из функции за ее пределы?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести полученное значение из select за пределы функции и использовать это значение в коде. Задача у меня такая. В выпадающем списке выбираю город и значение сразу должно меняться. После выбранное значение должно выводится вне функции.

Вот мой код. Помогите понять, как выводить значения за пределы.

```js
let site = [{
    "id": 698740,
    "name": "Odesa",
    "state": "",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 30.732622,
      "lat": 46.477474
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 699844,
    "name": "Ivanovka",
    "state": "",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.24807,
      "lat": 44.937309
    }
  }, {
    "id": 700177,
    "name": "Mykolayivka",
    "state": "",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.606361,
      "lat": 46.107071
    }
  },
]


let siteName = document.querySelector('.wrp_body');
let weaterNum = document.querySelector('.weater_num');
let divS = document.querySelector('.site');

// Создаем select
let sel = document.createElement('select');
sel.className = 'select';
siteName.prepend(sel);

// Перебираем массив городов и добавляем в созданный селект
for (let i = 0; i < site.length; i++) {
  let opt = document.createElement('option');
  sel.append(opt);
  opt.value = site[i]['id'];
  opt.textContent = site[i]['name'];
}

// НЕ ПОЙМУ КАК СДЕЛАТЬ ЭТУ ЧАСТЬ И ВЫВЕСТИ ЗА ПРЕДЕЛЫ ПОЛУЧАЕМОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
let val = 1;

function aLu(val) {
  val = this.value;
  return val;
}
let seLect = document.querySelector('.select').addEventListener('change', aLu);

// СЮДА НУЖНО ВЫВЕСТИ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ
weaterNum.innerHTML = val;
```

```html
<div class="wrp_body">
  <div class="weater_num h2">30 C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, проблема в том, что у вас нет чёткого разделения между кодом, который исполняется последовательно и синхронно, и кодом, который исполняется в ответ на событие асинхронно. Если вы хотите, чтобы каждое изменение в списке изменяло содержимое `weaterNum`, вам нужно не значение выводить их обработчика события, а обновление `weaterNum` вносить в обработчик:

```
function aLu() {
  weaterNum.innerHTML = this.value;
}
document.querySelector('.select').addEventListener('change', aLu);
```

Comment: Я хочу вывести за пределы функции в переменную = n. Но никак не пойму как? 
document.querySelector('.select').addEventListener('change', function ae() {
    let n = this.value;
})

let n = ae();

У меня есть ниже код, в который нужно вставить полученный город.

Comment: Возможно, я не понимаю вашей ситуации. Как говорится, асинхронность заразна. Если у вас что-то зависит от асинхронного события (пользователь выбирает город), всё зависимое должно вызываться изнутри обработчика асинхронного события. Так что код, которые использует полученный город, нужно или вносить в обработчик тоже, или вызывать из него как функцию с параметром этого города.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt `let seLect = ` — этот кусок ничего не делает, кстати) addEventListener ничего не возвращает, это ничего записывается в переменную seLect (которую не надо вОтТаК называть), которая позже уничтожается...

Comment: Да, вы правы, я отредактирую.